# bind variables with where clause

Tags: sql

I have select statement like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Employee_column = :P_EmplId;
```

After running this query I got error (incorrect syntax near ':' ) Can some one help me what I need to do to avoid this error.

Comment: Can you post the complete `select` statement. which database you are using.

Comment: Are you trying to compare the contents of `col1` with a string containing a colon, e.g. `WHERE ':' = col1`? What other meaning might you have in mind?

Comment: Different databases and different providers and different libraries  require a different syntax for command parameters. What DB do you have? How do you open the DB (connect string, provider etc.)? I never saw this `:=col1`!

Comment: You are trying to have parameter input here. In static embedded SQL you specify host variables like this. Either replace with a value, or a parameter marker (? character).

Comment: Which DBMS (Postgres, Oracl3e, ..) and programming (Java, Pascal, ...) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic SQL?:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 WHERE col1='somevalue' AND col2='somevalue' AND col3 = 'somevalue';
```